# How to make PIXI.text ready for retina displays?

Tags: pixi.js

I've used the approach described in [documents of PIXI](https://web.archive.org/web/20171203090730/http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixi-js-v2-fastest-2d-webgl-renderer/) for supporting retina displays:

```
var myRenderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 600, {
  resolution:myDisplayResolution
});
```

`@2x` images work fine but `PIXI.text` nodes are still blurred, how can I make them look sharp in retina displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that PIXI.Text has it's own resolution option. So you have to set it accordingly on each text node that you add to your stage.

Try doing like this and see if it works.

```
    var some_text = new PIXI.Text('I\'m so blurry', some_style);
    var some_other_text = new PIXI.Text('I\'m so fancy!', some_style);
    some_text.x = 50
    some_text.y = 50

    stage.addChild(some_text);

    some_other_text.x = 50
    some_other_text.y = 150        
    some_other_text.resolution = myDisplayResolution;

    stage.addChild(some_other_text);
```

Comment: Thank you. It had a great effect on the sharpness of the text elements

Comment: No ptoblem. Glad I could help. :)